# Prove by contradiction that $A\cup B=B\cup A.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

For arbitrary sets $A$ and $B$, assume the opposite of our conclusion: $A\cup B \neq B \cup A$.

Thus, either there exists $x\in (A \cup B)$ such that $x \notin (B\cup A)$ or there exists $x'\in (B\cup A)$ such that $x' \notin (A\cup B)$.
Without loss of generality, assume the first condition, that there exists $x \in (A\cup B)$ such that $x \notin (B\cup A)$. Then $x\notin B$ and $x\notin A$, or in other words, $x\notin A$ and $x\notin B$.
So, $x\notin (A\cup B)$, a contradiction.

From this antilogy, it follows that $A\cup B = B\cup A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works, but I recommend a direct proof instead: for all $x$,

$$\begin{align}
x\in A\cup B&\iff x\in A\lor x\in B\\
&\iff x\in B\lor x\in A\\
&\iff x\in B\cup A.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Now I've got a different question. While preparing myself to start my math major I've picked up on the fact that most of sets properties are proved in the way you pointed out. So my questions is, Do I always have to prove a statement in the easiest way (I don't mean by the direct method). Why would you recommend a direct proof instead? I would appreciate your response. I've not even started university.

Comment: @NewSelfTaughtMathematician Many student proofs by contradiction, including yours, are basically direct proofs with a bit of which-is-a-contradiction wrapping you don't need, and in that case I advise showing the direct part. But in general, prove it however you like. As for why proofs in set theory often take my approach, it's because the algebra of sets is isomorphic to that of propositions.

Comment: Much obliged. :D